# Converting a string to a symbol

Tags: ruby, string, symbols

I am trying to read a string from an array and convert it into a symbol without the quotes `""`. For example, given:

```
my_array = ["apples", "oranges", "pears"]
```

I would like variable `my_first_fruit` to return `:apples`. I tried:

```
my_first_fruit = my_array[0].to_sym
```

but, it comes out as:

```
my_first_fruit = :"apples"
```

and I cannot seem to get rid of the `""`. If I type

```
my_first_fruit = "apples"
my_first_fruit.to_sym
```

It then returns `:apples`. Why is that?

Comment: `my_array[0].to_sym`... what's the *real* issue? And what's your purpose? If you print the string, e.g., `puts my_array[0]`, the quotes won't be printed.

Comment: what is the real issue? It is "how to remove quotes from the name of a symbol when converting from strings". It's simple as that! I gave a basic example using non-compounding words, but once the answer below was provided, i applied it, then I saw that the problem was NOT the method, but the type of string (compound). Is that any clearer?

Comment: Dave try this: array = ["orange juice", "apple sauce", "pears", "grape fruit"]. Then, do array[0].to_sym. You will get :"orange juice" <--a symbol name with quotes!!!

Then, replace the spaces in the above array with under score or no space at all and you get :orange_juice <--symbol with NO quotes! That is what I wanted.

Comment: You made a claim that the code you provided worked in the way you claim. It doesn't, as *I* claimed, hence asking what the *real* issue is, because it's *not* what you posted. Not posting code that actually demonstrates the problem is worse than useless. `to_sym` works just fine with the data you provided, as both my comment and answer state.

Comment: If you look at what my post was about, it was asking a question. Simple answer like the one that was provided helped me. It wasn't a CLAIM. It was a question.

Comment: Oh, now I'm an asshole for telling you to actually demonstrate the problem you're asking about? Even though my_first_fruit *isn't* = `:"apples"`? You explicitly said code did what it doesn't do, which is why my comment asked what the real problem is, because there *aren't* any problems with the code you posted, and it doesn't do what you say it does. And in your comment to the answer you explicitly *describe* the real problem--so your question *isn't* accurate, and you *know* it isn't, and you're butt-hurt because people noticed. Good luck--I'd suggest a different approach and attitude.

Comment: `my_first_fruit = my_array[0].to_sym` produces a symbol *without* quotes, on my machine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the [`String#to_sym` method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-to_sym):

```ruby
"apples".to_sym # => :apples

my_array = ["apples", "oranges", "pears"].map(&:to_sym)
my_array[0] # => :apples
```

See also [`String#intern`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-intern).

Comment: Ok, I just did that and it works! One thing I noticed that I failed to mention and maybe others will consider this: if you have spaces for example my_array = ["apple sauce", "orange juice", "pears"] Ruby will force the quotes!! So, when I applied your method (maerics) it worked perfectly on the real array, but still caused ("") to appear on the values that had spaces. So, my solution was to substitute the  spaces for _ <---under score, and....PRESTO! I am all good! Thanks!!

Comment: @user2639390 So the example you provided didn't actually produce the output you claimed?

Comment: it did produce it but it was mixed. For the values that had no space, it worked. For the values that had a space it remained the same. So, I made sure and added that unbeknownst to me, spaces will ALWAYS cause the quotes to be added to a symbol when doing the conversion.

Comment: Moral of the story: if you want to have a string convert to a symbol and NOT have quotes added, take out the spaces or replace with another value like under score (_).

Comment: @user2639390 The real moral: don't provide an example that doesn't exhibit the behavior you're claiming.

Comment: Dave, get a life dude. I am new to this, but I don't need to take crap for something that you obviously can coach me on. Maybe you'd be better fit for writing a "how to use Stackflow" handbook instead of picking fights with people who are working hard to accomplish a goal.

Comment: @user2639390 I *am* coaching you, on how to ask a question. For example, I'd recommend not posting code that doesn't demonstrate the problem you're having, because otherwise people will look at it and believe you're not actually asking the right question, which you weren't. You're welcome. Oh, and telling me to "get a life" when you're the one who fell short is rude.

Comment: Let me know when I can sign up to the Stackflow for dummies video blog/class/workshop.

Comment: @user2639390 http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html and http://sscce.org/, which had you provided it, would have led to a quicker, more accurate answer. Notice that the answer given mirrors my comment precisely. If you have additional information, *edit the question*.

Answer (score 3):

To summarize:

The issue is that **when you convert a string with spaces** (ie: "Johnny Appleseed") using '.to_sym', the converted symbol will show as :"Johnny Appleseed". This is due to the space between 'Johnny' and 'Appleseed' -- and will not occur if you are just converting "apples", "oranges", or "pears".

If you don't want quotes, use underscores in your string instead of spaces.

---

**For example:**

```
my_array = ["apple juice", "oranges", "pears"]
my_array.collect! {|fruit| fruit.to_sym}
```

will produce:

```
my_array[0] = :"apple juice"
my_array[1] = :oranges
```